# decompile and compile Jar File

Tags: java, javafx, jar, compilation, decompiling

we have a problem at work right now. We have a jar file without corresponding source code from a software. We only have older versions of the code. But we need to make changes to the current source code. So I tried to decompile the jar file with "jd-gui.exe". But while compiling the decompiled file errors occur. We currently have no Java programmers in the company. And I hardly know anything about Java. Do I have to pay attention to something when decompiling and recompiling or are there other ways to get the code.

Thanks in advance

[image]

Comment: Add the original jar to the class path. This solves most of the problems :)

Comment: how can i do it

Comment: Configure Build Path in eclipse.

Comment: this doesnt worked

Answer (score 0):

I think you have a jar file and you try to decompile that file to get source code.
some days ago I solve this type of problem by using online tools.

you can try this :

[Java decompiler](http://www.javadecompilers.com/)

but it is hard to understand source code if there was no comment. so you need to patient to understand and compile it again